# Isomorphic trees numeration

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, discrete-mathematics

I have two graphs representing some isomorphic (with the same shape) trees and I want to match each vertex from first graph with corresponding vertex from second one. There are N vertecies with numbers from 0 to N - 1.[image]

For example, for node 2 in left tree the output should be node 3 in right tree. As far as I understood, sometimes there is no unique solution. In this case any of them would be good.

My first approach was BFS from node with max degree and matching, but it wouldn't work with two or more nodes with the same degree. Also, it should be O(N) or O(NlogN) solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What would `5` and `6` map to, since there's an ambiguity there (either `0` or `4` would work)? This is somewhat crucial to solve (per "two or more nodes with the same degree" not working), but it can be done arbitrarily if your solution allows for it. Basically as you iterate down your tree via BFS, you'll end up with children that have a matching `deg`, and so long as the children's children (recursively) have matching degrees, you should be fine. Mathematically, this just demonstrates that there is more than 1 isomorphism to choose from, but all are correct.

Comment: 5 and 6 from left can be mapped to 0 and 4 both ways: (5->0 and 6->4) or (5->4 and 6->0). Both of them are correct

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/graph-theory-isomorphic-trees-7d48aa577e46

Comment: So as long as you don't have any specific constraints (e.g. mapping with least-distances, which would necessitate `5->0` and `6->4`), then you can simply pick one provided that the node is truly an isomorphic match (check the children!)

Comment: So, checking children is sufficient condition to get one of correct matches?

Comment: @egor The [tag:c++] tag is preserved for questions about specific  c++ coding problems. As there's no c++ code in your question I removed that tag from it.

Comment: Basically if you only went off degree matching, imagine a tree node where two child nodes `A` and `B` had degree 2. `A` only has a single child of degree 1 (a leaf), but `B` has a child of degree 2. Thus, `A` and `B` would not match up in isomorphism, despite having the same degree. Hence, check the children to ensure they do actually match. If you hit an ambiguity (two nodes have the same children in terms of degrees, and their children and so on), then you can arbitrarily pick whichever one fancies you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Specify what exactly makes two trees identical.

As an example, let us suppose that you can consider two trees identical if, and only if, the number of children in each of the nodes beneath the root are identical.

2. Define a data structure that contains, and only contains, the information in the specification ( 1  ).  Attach an instance of the data structure to each node.   Define an overload of the == operator that accurately checks specification ( 1 )

e.g.  node 2 on the left has one leaf child and one child with two leaf children

3. Starting at each leaf node (excluding the roots ) work back towards the root filling in the data structures ( 2 )
4. Check that the data structures of the two root nodes are ==  ( If not the trees are NOT isomophic )
5. Starting at the roots work down the trees, linking the nodes that are identical